# Limit POST Request

Tags: java, spring

I implemented an int variable for counter. Since I only have POST method, I cannot set again `forgetPasswordCounter` to 0. That's why it doesn't work how exactly I want. How exactly can I make limit for requests?

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
  private static int forgetPasswordCounter = 0;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/forgetpassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity < String > forgetPassword(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username) throws Exception {
    while (forgetPasswordCounter < 3) {
      Client foundUser = globalServices.findClientByUsername(username);    
      if (null != foundUser) {
        ...
        forgetPasswordCounter++;
        return new ResponseEntity < String > (responseMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
      ...
      forgetPasswordCounter++;
      return new ResponseEntity < String > (responseMessage, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    String responseMessage = "Too many requests";
    return new ResponseEntity < String > (responseMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you make it as map with adding user name and counter?
Also you can also how many time left after last try and then if necessary reset counter.

Comment: When do you want your password counter reset? And why aren't you setting it to 0 on `HttpStatus.OK`

Comment: IMO you should save this count in the database and when you retrieve your `Client`you can check if the count is less then 3

Comment: I would put this on database because it can be lost if your application stop and you lose the count for some reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think you don't take the good way to solve your problem...

First, have a static counter in your controller is not a good idea. Show the spring documentation section "Bean scopes".
You can keep it in database and access to it via your "globalServices" by example.

Anyway, I suppose that you hope have more than one user, so you need to get this counter by username-> Before your condition.

Then, don't use a "while" loop instruction instead of "if".

Finally, rather than use a simple counter you can define a reinitialization which take account the date of last authorized password sending (it is a simple advise there is a lot of possible strategies to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Client` should have the `count` and make something like this. The reason to save this on database is simple, if something happen to your application and you need to restart or if the server get down for some reason you don't lose the count for any `Client`

```
public ResponseEntity < String > forgetPassword(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username) throws Exception {
      Client foundUser = globalServices.findClientByUsername(username);    
      if(foundUser.getCountOfForgetPassword() <= 3){  
            globalServices.updateCountOfForgetPassword(++foundUser.getCountOfForgetPassword());
            return new ResponseEntity < String > (responseMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
      }
      String responseMessage = "Too many requests";
      return new ResponseEntity < String > (responseMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding to your comments above, I thought that I could at least avoid from getting request spammed with this method I tried to implement. I tested on some famous websites that when I clicked request buttons(like forget/change password) 3-4 times, the server gives 429 status error and after 10-15mins, I was able to click the request buttons.

Comment: you can save the date like `lastTimeOfRequest` if the date was too soon you could block it, i don't know any other way to do this..